# Is it possible to store os_log message to a text file? Or is it possible to use method swizzling to observe the os_log() function call?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have two iOS apps written in Objective-c. For one of the Apps i am using my own logging functionality.I am storing the logs in local Database and sending the log messages to server for debugging and checking performance of app.

In the other App i have used os_log for logging. In most of the places I am using the following line to log events.
os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "Log message goes here");

Now I want to store these logs to local DB and send it to my server. Is it possible to do this?

I read in some article that we can use method swizzling to log events. Is it possible to use method swizzling here. If not, is there any way to save the os_log messages to local db.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new macro to call os_log and save method

```
#define my_log(p1, p2) [MyLog logWithParam:p1 p2:p2]

@interface MyLog : NSObject

+(void)logWithParam:(NSString*)p1 p2:(NSString*)p2;

@end

@implementation MyLog

+(void)logWithParam:(NSString*)p1 p2:(NSString*)p2{
    os_log(p1, p2);
    [self saveLogToLocalFile];
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't want to change the existing implementation. All the os_log(); function calls should be as is. But i want to create one more class that observes for the os_log() function calls and store the messages in local file.